# Cannot connect mongoose with express rest api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, connection

I'm trying to create a rest api with express and connect to mongodb, I create a script to do the job and import it in the app.js file :

***app.js***

```
import express from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import mongoose from './config/mongoose.connection.js'
import logger from './config/logger.js'
import { port, env } from './config/vars.js'

const app = express();


app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(dotenv.config)

// start server

app.listen(port, () => {
    logger.info(`server started on port ${port} (${env})`)
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});

// open mongoose connection
mongoose.connectDB();
```

***mongoose.connection.js***

```
import { Promise as _Promise, connection, set, connect } from 'mongoose';
import { error } from './logger.js';
import { mongo, env } from './vars.js';

// set mongoose Promise to Bluebird
_Promise = Promise;

// Exit application on error
connection.on('error', (err) => {
    error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`);
    process.exit(-1);
});

// print mongoose logs in dev env
if (env === 'development') {
    set('debug', true);
}

/**
 * Connect to mongo db
 *
 * @returns {object} Mongoose connection
 * @public
 */
export function connect() {
    connect(mongo.uri, {
            useCreateIndex: true,
            keepAlive: 1,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        })
        .then(() => console.log('mongoDB connected...'));
    return connection;
}
```

when run the app I got this error :

> file:///home/sahnoun/Documents/Fwinr-BACKEND/src/config/mongoose.connection.js:25
> export function connect() {
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Identifier 'connect' has already been declared

Answer (score 0):

Always look at the error which is explicit enough in that case:

```
connect' has already been declared
```

You can see that you are importing the function `connect` as well as exporting a function named `connect`. Just rename your function.

```
export function connectToMongo() {
  connect(mongo.uri, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    keepAlive: 1,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
    .then(() => console.log('mongoDB connected...'));
  return connection;
}
```

**Bonus**

If you want to keep your function name `connect`, then in the import, use something like:

```
import { Promise as _Promise, connection, set, connect as connectToMongo } from 'mongoose';

export function connect() {
  connectToMongo(mongo.uri, {
  ...
```